# What is "log canonical threshold" in simple terms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, affine-varieties, singularity-theory, projective-varieties

I'm currently learning some basic algebraic geometry and am interested in singularities of varieties.

In reading about classifying singular points I've come across the log canonical threshold (LCT) as a tool to tell "how bad" a singularity is. I'm struggling to understand what the LCT actually is and where it comes from.
Does anyone know of a good place I can find a low-tech explanation of this?

Comment: The first section of this survey: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmtemf/files/BFK_Frobenius.pdf has a pretty down-to-earth discussion of LCT over $\mathbb C$, where everything can be expressed in terms of convergence of certain integrals.

Comment: This is really helpful, Thank you!